# How to compile my new Backbone, Marionette, Require app

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

I've learnt some JavaScript, then Backbone, then Require, then Marionette and I've build this little app that I simply run using file:/// in my browser.

I wanted to see how much it would weight and work after I compile and minify it.

I have no idea what tool should I use. RequireJS Optimizer? Should I install Grunt or something alike?

I also have this feeling that I should already had Node.js installed and run my app in localhost. Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already using node, then r.js is your tool (requireJs optimizer) 
you can just feed it with the build.js settings and specify the out file, here is an example:

```
 node node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js  -o build.js out=public/build/1.8.2/all.js
```

Comment: I've just started learning Node but I guess you're right! Thanks